# What does (loco) mean?

Tags: guitar, notation, clefs

I was reading the [classical guitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_guitar) article on wikipedia and saw this "(*loco)*" notation used to describe the playing range of guitar:

[image: staff showing an octave treble clef with pitch of guitar strings, high range shown with a clef change - to treble clef with "(loco)"]

What does "(loco)" mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Loco" means "in place", and in a musical context "at this exact pitch" and negates a previous "8va", "8vb" or similar marking. Guitar music sounds an octave lower than it is notated (the '8' under the treble clef on the left implies this, but it's not usually written). The notes on the right are the highest playable notes written as they sound *without* the octave transposition.

In case it's not clear: the notes on the left are the open strings (sounding an octave lower).